# Multiple Polygon On Map

Tags: android, google-maps

how to make multiple polygon on Google  Map I am using

```
List<lat long> data = new Array List<Lat Long>();
```

but its create only one polygon when we draw another then last polygon deleted so anyone please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show more code??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a common method to draw polygon on google maps like this:

```
public PolygonOptions addPolygon(ArrayList < LatLng > arg) {

    LatLng[] data = arg.toArray();
    PolygonOptions polygonOptions;

    for (int i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
        polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
        polygonOptions.add(data[i], data[i + 1], data[i + 2])).strokeColor(Color.RED).strokeWidth(2);
        polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.parseColor("#51000000"));
        return polygonOptions;
    }
}
```

and then add it to your GoogleMap like this:

```
yourGoogleMap.addPolygon(addPolygon(data));
```

Comment: you can accept and upvote my answer so that others may refer to this answer for future help.thanx by the way!!! @vikas

Comment: i am faced another problem when i make polygon clockwise its fine but when its clock+anticlockwise( Both Direction ) then stroke line will appear on fill color and the drawing spoiled

Comment: you need to show some of your code at least otherwise it will be very painful for me to understand.@vikas

Comment: for (int j = 0; j < maindata.size(); j++) {

    lines = new PolygonOptions();

    Log.i("main", "maindata values " + maindata.get(j));

    data = maindata.get(j);

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {

     lines.add(data.get(i));

     lines.strokeWidth(3);

     lines.strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

     lines.fillColor(Color.parseColor("#51000000"));

     googlemap.addPolygon(lines);
    }
   }
   maindata.clear();
   data.clear();